# Using Java 2D int array is giving TLE, while Using Integer 2D array is getting accepted. Why?

Tags: java, arrays

I was solving coin change 2 on leetcode.
I wrote code as below using int 2D array, its giving TLE:

```
class Solution {
    public int change(int amount, int[] coins, int tillIndex, int [][]ways){
        if(amount==0){
            return 1;
        }
        if(amount<0){
            return 0;
        }
        if(coins.length==0){
            return 0;
        }
        if(ways[tillIndex][amount] > 0){
            return ways[amount][tillIndex];
        }
        if(tillIndex == coins.length && amount > 0){
            return 0;
        }
        
        //include + exclude
        ways[tillIndex][amount]= change(amount-coins[tillIndex], coins, tillIndex, ways) + 
                                 change(amount, coins, tillIndex+1, ways);
        return ways[tillIndex][amount];
    }
    public int change(int amount, int[] coins) {
        int [][]ways= new int[coins.length+1][amount+1];
        return change(amount, coins, 0, ways);
    }
}
```

**But** when i am using Integer 2D array instead of int 2D array as below code, its getting accepted:

```
class Solution {
    public int change(int amount, int[] coins, int tillIndex, Integer [][]ways){
        if(amount==0){
            return 1;
        }
        if(amount<0){
            return 0;
        }
        if(coins.length==0){
            return 0;
        }
        if(ways[amount][tillIndex] != null){
            return ways[amount][tillIndex];
        }
        if(tillIndex == coins.length && amount > 0){
            return 0;
        }
        
        //include + exclude
        ways[amount][tillIndex]= change(amount-coins[tillIndex], coins, tillIndex, ways) + 
                                 change(amount, coins, tillIndex+1, ways);
        return ways[amount][tillIndex];
    }
    public int change(int amount, int[] coins) {
        Integer [][]ways= new Integer[amount+1][coins.length+1];
        return change(amount, coins, 0, ways);
    }
}
```

I know Java is pass by value, and array being passed is treated as an object.
Then what's the issue here?

Comment: This feature is known as [Autoboxing and Unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).

Comment: I got the solution. Its due to a miniscule error in logic of my code. Its not related to Java.